# KeyError: word not in vocabulary， when I use gensim.Word2Vec to process chinese tokens

Tags: python, nlp, word2vec, gensim, keyerror

code like this:

```
train_corpus = "sentence_all.txt"
sentences = LineSentence(train_corpus)
model = Word2Vec(sentences, size=vector_size,  window=window_size, min_count=min_count, workers=worker_count, iter=train_epoch)
print(model['一九九八年新年'])
```

the corpus file has been processd as list of token by LineSentence in gensim like this:

```
['本报', '讯', '河北邢台中桥商场', '以', '诚', '待客', ',', '以', '真品', '赢', '来', '回头客', '。', '1997年', ',', '商场', '利税', '比', '上年', '翻', '了', '一番', '多', ',', '员工', '人均', '年', '销售额', '达', '22.1万', '元', '。']
['中桥商场', '虽', '地处', '邢台市', ',', '但', '为了', '扩大', '销售', '半径', ',', '他们', '投资', '近', '万', '元', ',', '向', '邢台市', '19', '个', '县', '、', '市', '、', '区', '部分', '顾客', '赠阅', '《', '公关', '世界', '》', '及', '《', '中国', '质量', '万', '里', '行', '》', '杂志', ',', '扩大', '了', '商店', '的', '影响', '。']
```

then get the error:

```
KeyError: "word '一九九八年新年' not in vocabulary"
```

but only a few tokens are not in vocabulary, the others can get their word vector, then I don't know the reason.

Comment: Why do you think '一九九八年新年' _should_ be in the model, in the first place?

Comment: Why don't you put it in a try-except block?

Answer (score 0):

```
gensim.models.Word2Vec(sen, size=100, workers=4, min_count=1)

set min_count=1
```

`min_count` means ignore all words with total frequency lower than this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is because the embedding of the word you are trying to get does not exist. You cannot query a word which is not in the dictionary of words which were fed to the model while training.

I hope this answers your question.